# Data Explorer seems to half attempt to nest comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, data-explorer

I have embedded a start comment in a comment in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66265/comment-test) and its `Order By` clause is ignored:

```sql
Select 1 As [F]
Union all
Select 2 As [F]
/*/**/
Order By [F] DESC
```

...yields:

```
 F
--
 1
 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue is that you don't get a syntax exception for not closing the second comment. Running the SQL as-is produces the following error in SSMS:

> Msg 113, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Missing end comment mark '*/'.

Data Explorer is currently removing comments from your query prior to execution, and doesn't handle cases like this appropriately. I'll see what can be done about cases like this; it might just be better if Data Explorer doesn't try to do what it's doing  now so errors like this would be thrown by SQL Server.

For right now though, I [took care of](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=6863b7c6ea7258f96057fd2cd914be2bda3ef077) this specific case.

Comment: Either this change never went live, or something is stopping the added error to occur.

Comment: Hasn't gone live yet. We're working on getting everything reviewed and pushed out ASAP (lots of changes in the pipe), sorry for the delay.